# Error when running if function on mysql results

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to set permissions in a MySQL table, But i get the error:

```
Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in 
/public/sites/staffpaneel.mc-wonderland.nl/index.php on line 656

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted 
to string in /public/sites/staffpaneel.mc-wonderland.nl/index.php on line 679
```

Does anyone has i fix for this, I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked

```
    <?php
    //Perms
    $PermissiesUitlezen = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `RankPermissies` WHERE RankID ° '".$sqlDataIngelogd['RankID']."'");
    $sqlDataPermissies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PermissiesUitlezen);

if ($conn->query($PermissiesUitlezen) === TRUE) {
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['AccountMakenMag'] == 1) {
        AccountMakenMag();
    }
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['AccountsMag'] == 1) {
        AccountsMag();
    }
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['MeldingMakenMag'] == 1) {
        MeldingMakenMag();
    }
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['RankAanmakenMag'] == 1) {
        RankAanmakenMag();
    }
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['RanksMag'] == 1) {
        RanksMag();
    }
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['StoringMakenMag'] == 1) {
        StoringMakenMag();
    }
    if ($sqlDataPermissies['StoringenMag'] == 1) {
        StoringenMag();
    }
} else {
    echo "Fout: " . $PermissiesUitlezen . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
    ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: php and mysqli tells you exactly what's wrong in this particular case...

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$PermissiesUitlezen` hold the result of a `mysqli_query()` call and in the `if` you use this as a parameter of another `mysqli_query()` call. This does not make any sense.

Actually, had you read the manual on [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) on php.net, you would know how to properly check for errors:

```
 if ($PermissiesUitlezen = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `RankPermissies` WHERE RankID = '".$sqlDataIngelogd['RankID']."'")) {
     $sqlDataPermissies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PermissiesUitlezen);
     ...
```

Note, that I also corrected the sql statement (replaced `°` with `=` . But pls also note that you should use prepared statements if you have parameters in your sql query.

Comment: I now have:
    `
      $sqlRankIngelogdPerms = $sqlDataIngelogd['RankID'];
      $PermissiesUitlezen = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `RankPermissies` WHERE RankID = '".$sqlRankIngelogdPerms."'");`

But it still doesn't works, how do i fix this from now

Comment: I'm not a mind reader to figure out the error message you are getting. Pls also note that if you are getting a different subsequent error message, then you may have to ask a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

can you change your query from

```
SELECT * FROM `RankPermissies` WHERE RankID ° '".$sqlDataIngelogd['RankID']."'
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM `RankPermissies` WHERE RankID = '".$sqlDataIngelogd['RankID']."'
```

Then check.